# Running IBM mq on virtual Machine or on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-mq

I want to find a way of running IBM mq on kubernetes . Without using openshift.

Comment: Maybe this link can help [Building your own IBM MQ container](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=containers-building-your-own-mq-container).

Comment: You need to add what you have tried and what specific problems you are having.